# Can't read data from Postgres to Kafka

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

Can't read data from Postgres to Kafka. I connected Kafka to my Postgres database by debezium in docker. But when I run kafkacat in docker to read postgres I get an error

```
ERROR: Failed to format message in postgres.public.users [0] at offset 0:  Avro/Schema-registry message deserialization: REST request failed (code -1): HTTP request failed: Couldn't resolve host name : terminating
```

I run kafkacat by the command:

```
docker run --tty --network pythonproject5_default confluentinc/cp-kafkacat kafkacat -b kafka:9092 -C -s key=s -s value=avro -r http://schema-regisrty:8081 -t postgres.public.users
```

debezium connector file looks like this

```
{
"name": "db-connector",
"config": {
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
"plugin.name": "pgoutput",
"database.hostname": "postgres",
"database.port": "5432",
"database.user": "George",
"database.password": "tech1337",
"database.dbname": "tech_db",
"database.server.name": "postgres",
"table.include.list": "public.users"
}
}
```

schemas in application looks like this:

```
name: str
time_created: int
gender: str
age: int
last_name: str
ip: str
city: str
premium: bool = None
birth_day: str
balance: int
user_id: int
```

and model like this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    name = Column(String)
    time_created = Column(Integer)
    gender = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    last_name = Column(String)
    ip = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    premium = Column(Boolean)
    birth_day = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    my_vet = relationship("VET", back_populates="owner")
```

docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=goerge
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tech1337
      - POSTGRES_DB=5_pm_db

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.3
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "5056:5056"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:   PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092 \
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.5.3
    depends_on: [zookeeper]
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9991
    ports:
      - 9092:9092

  debezium:
    image: debezium/connect:1.4
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      GROUP_ID: 1
      CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_configs
      OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offsets
      KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema- registry:8081
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL:  http://schema-registry:8081
    depends_on: [kafka]
    ports:
      - 8083:8083

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
    environment:
     - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
     - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
     - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema- registry:8081,http://localhost:8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on: [zookeeper, kafka]
```

All operation in code with Postgres's I realised in SQLAlchemy.
If anyone get this error please write how you handle with this and how can I fix this error?

Comment: `Couldn't resolve host name`... Are you sure `--network` value is correct? Can you show your compose file?

Comment: Where are you setting `value.converter.schema.registry.url`?

Comment: edit question to show my compose file

Answer (score 0):

> Avro/Schema-registry message deserialization: REST request failed

This needs to be `http://0.0.0.0:8081`, which is the default value.

```
SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://schema- registry:8081,http://localhost:8081
```

Also, you need to remove spaces in `schema- registry` in all the other places this is used.

Alternatively, don't use AvroConverters, and use something else that doesn't need the Registry, such as JSONConverter

```
KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

You also can remove the `broker` service since it is never used in your Compose

Comment: I already has these settings in my code  @OneCricketeer but the error keeps reappearing.